# Export AmCharts to image/pdf in React application

Tags: reactjs, amcharts

Working on an application bootstrapped with create-react-app.
I need to export amChart to jpg/png/pdf formats.
I'm trying to export like in this codepen I've found: [codepen export amchart example](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/e487525e17e43a9d2de41d71f525b721)

```
            var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chart-header", {
                "type": "pie",
                "theme": "light",
                "dataProvider": [ {
                    "country": "Czech Republic",
                    "litres": 301.9
                }, {
                    "country": "Austria",
                    "litres": 128.3
                }, {
                    "country": "UK",
                    "litres": 99
                }, {
                    "country": "The Netherlands",
                    "litres": 50
                }],
                "valueField": "litres",
                "titleField": "country",
                "export": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "menu": []
                }
            })

            chart["export"].capture({}, function() {
                this.toPNG({}, function(base64) {
                    console.log(base64)                   
                })
            })
```

But it doesn't work in my case. It gives me: `Uncaught TypeError: chart.export.capture is not a function` all the time.

Answer (score 0):

So.. right or wrong, below is the simplified solution I've found.
On click "export" button, I make `this.setState({ shouldExportChart: true })`. **In the "render" event listener** I check whether it's `true`, if so, perform export and set to `false`. 
In the same way, calling `this.toJPG()` we can export to JPG format.
For PDF generation I used jspdf, for archiving - jszip.

Dependencies in `package.json`:

```
"@amcharts/amcharts3-react": "^3.0.3",
"amcharts3": "^3.21.13",
"amcharts3-export": "github:amcharts/export"
"file-saver": "^1.3.3",
"fabric-webpack": "^1.6.0-rc.1"
```

Component.jsx:

```
import 'amcharts3'
import AmCharts from '@amcharts/amcharts3-react'
import 'amcharts3-export'
import 'fabric-webpack'
import  FileSaver from 'file-saver'

const chartConfig = {
            options: {
                ...,
                "export": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "menu": []
                },
                "listeners": [
                    {
                        event: 'rendered',
                        method: (e) => {
                            if (window.fabric) {
                                e.chart.export.capture({}, function () {
                                    this.toPNG({}, function (base64) {
                                        this.toBlob({
                                            data: base64,
                                            type: 'image/png'
                                         }, (blob) => {
                                             FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'chart.png')
                                         })
                                     })                               
                                })
                            }
                        }   
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

        <AmCharts.React {...chartConfig} />
```